# "Pass a variable from React to Dialogflow, use it in ES query params, then embed the result back in the React app."

Tags: python, reactjs

I have created a dialogue flow ES for the insurance company, "Is there any way to pass a variable from the react web app to the dialogue flow, later need to use further pass in the dialogue flow ES query params, that will be embedded in the react app",

For eg, If an user account "ABC" have access to invoke my agent via insurance company app, on the welcome intent I have to send a response like "Welcome ABC". How do I achieve this with insurance company  app is my endpoint.

I have tried with context.